# How to create one instance of a frame at a time

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Im using wxWidgets with my c++ application.

I have a wxGrid setup in which users can double-click on a cell and that will create a new window with another grid.

Im having an issue with closing and reopening the new window with grid.

```
void FeatureList::mouseDClick(wxGridEvent& event)
{
int n_row, n_col;
n_row = event.GetRow();
n_col = 0;

m_sCellValue = grid->GetCellValue(n_row, n_col); 

if ( frame == NULL ) // If frame is closed
{
    CreateCrackBoxFrame(m_sCellValue);
}
else{
    frame->Raise();  // otherwise bring it to the front.
}
}

void FeatureList::CreateCrackBoxFrame(wxString m_sCellValue)
{
frame = new CrackBoxFrame(m_pvFeatures, m_sCellValue, m_bDisplayInMetric);
frame->Show(true);
}

CrackBoxFrame::CrackBoxFrame(vector<Feature> *pvFeatures, wxString CellValue, 
bool bDisplayInMetric)
: wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("CrackBoxes"),wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(725, 
400))
{
 }
```

If i close the new window, and click on another cell my program crashes

Comment: Are you trying to run the external application from the wxGrid double-click event?

Comment: its not an external application. Feature list is a window within my app that has a grid setup. If a double click happens on the grid it creates a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have couple of options:

1. Keep the vector of lines and when the line in the grid is clicked, check if the appropriate line is clicked from the vector and allow the event to go only if it was not clicked.
2. Disable the line after the click has been processed and don't let the second one go thru.
3. Add the checkbox on every line in the grid and check it on the first click. On the subsequent ones - check if the value is not checked.

You choose...

Thank you.

---

EDIT:

```
void FeatureList::CreateCrackBoxFrame(wxString m_sCellValue)
{
    frame = new CrackBoxFrame(m_pvFeatures, m_sCellValue, m_bDisplayInMetric);
    frame->Show(true);
    frame->Bind( wxEVT_CLOSE, &FeatureList::OnCrackBoxClose, this );
}
```

Comment: Im able to create only one instance but im running into an issue, once the new window is created and is open everything works like its supposed too. but once i close the window and try to double click to re open the window my program crashes.

Comment: @MaazAzeem, which algorythm did you use? You need to unlock the line for that vframe on the close event... The best would probably be sending the custom event back to the frame with grid along with some id.

Comment: Instead of disabling the individual grid line im disabling the option to create a new frame, I have updated the code for reference. Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: @MaazAzeem, I updated my answer, but this is just RTFM. You can also check the `event` sample for that.